# Sum of residuals in multiple regression equals 0

Tags: econometrics, statistics

I understand that in multiple regression 
$$\sum_{}^{} X_{i,j}\hat{u}_{i} = 0 $$
 but I do not understand how my textbook says that if we include the intercept in the regression ($X_{i,0} = 1$)then we get:
$$\sum_{}^{} \hat{u}_{i} = 0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completing the notation with the indices
$$
\forall j: \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i,j}\hat{u}_{i} = 0.
$$
As you say, if $X_0$ is the constant then
$$
\forall i: X_{i,0} = 1.
$$
Inputing $j = 0$ into the first equation
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i,0}\hat{u}_{i} & = 0 \\
\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n} 1\hat{u}_{i} & = 0 \\
\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \hat{u}_{i} & = 0.
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 1):

When an intercept is included, sum of residuals in multiple regression equals 0.

In multiple regression, 
$$
\hat{y}_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{i,1} + \beta_2x_{i,2} +…+ \beta_px_{i,p}
$$
In Least squares regression, the sum of the squares of the errors is minimized.
$$
SSE=\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(e_i \right)^2= \sum_{i=1}^n\left(y_i - \hat{y_i} \right)^2= \sum_{i=1}^n\left(y_i -\beta_0- \beta_1x_{i,1}-\beta_2x_{i,2}-…- \beta_px_{i,p} \right)^2
$$
Take the partial derivative of SSE with respect to $\beta_0$ and setting it to zero.
$$
\frac{\partial{SSE}}{\partial{\beta_0}} = \sum_{i=1}^n 2\left(y_i -\beta_0- \beta_1x_{i,1}-\beta_2x_{i,2}-…- \beta_px_{i,p} \right)^1 (-1) = -2\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat{y_i})=-2\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^ne_i=0
$$
Hence, when an intercept is included, sum of residuals in multiple regression equals 0.